# substitute a regex in a string in batch

Tags: batch-file

I need to delete everything starting with a word from a string in a windows batch script.
For example if I have the string:

```
This is my line delete from here.
```

I want to delete everything starting with the word delete and I need to obtain:

```
This is my line.
```

I have tryed this:

```
set line="This is my line delete from here"
set word="delete"
set delete="!word!*";
set line=!line:%delete%=!
```

It doesn't work what I have tryed, I have activated delayed expansion, and I am not sure if this: "set line=!line:%delete%=!" works. I have tryed this too "set line=!line:!delete!=!" but doesn't work either. I am new with batch scripting.

UPDATE:
In a loop I can only do delayed expansion, and this code doesn't work:

```
@ECHO OFF

setlocal
for /F "delims= " %%A in (temp.txt) do ( 
    set "line=This is my line delete from here"
    ECHO original:%line%:
    set "word=delete"
    CALL set "delete=%%line:*%word%=%%"
    ECHO delete the "%word%%delete%" part
    CALL set "line=%%line:%word%%delete%=%%"
    ECHO final   :%line%:
)
endlocal
```

Output:

```
original::
=%" was unexpected at this time.
delete the "" part
=%" was unexpected at this time.
final   ::
```

But if I remove the for from the code above, the output is:

```
original:This is my line delete from here:
delete the "delete from here" part
final   :This is my line :
```

My question is how can I do the same thing in a loop, with delayed expansion, as with normal expansion. I need in other words late expansion for both variables in the substitution expression the inner and the outer (set "delete=!line:*!word!=!", doesn't work). I can not find any documentation on that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set "line=This is my line delete from here"
ECHO original:%line%:
set "word=delete"
CALL set "delete=%%line:*%word%=%%"
ECHO delete the "%word%%delete%" part
CALL set "line=%%line:%word%%delete%=%%"
ECHO final   :%line%:

GOTO :EOF
```

This should show you the steps.

First, delete the part up to and including the word. Then delete the word and the rest-of-line (in `delete`)

Note the placement of the quotes - to control the `set` not the value assigned.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works in a separate batch script but if include this inside a for it doesn't work. Inside my for I can only do  delayed expansion, and I don't know how to translate this code to work with delayed expansion.

Comment: These questions are always easier if we have all of the details, otherwise it becomes a never-ending series of supplemental questions that may drastically affect the approach taken.

Comment: I can not expand in my code the variable like this %var%, but like this !var!, and I was wondering which is the syntaxfor deleting the substring only by using late expansion.

Comment: Here ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723105/variables-expansion-inside-for-in-batch? )I have asked a question regarding the variable expansion inside for. Aparentlely I can not expand a variable like this %var% inside for.

Comment: That depends on what the real data is, and which parts are being changed.

Answer (score 0):

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905625/batch-scripting-help-replace-substring-of-a-delayedexpansion-var-with-another) and the updated code based on [Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947/magoo)'s answer:

```
@ECHO OFF

setlocal
for /F "delims= " %%A in (temp.txt) do ( 
    set "line=This is my line delete from here"
    set "word=delete"
    echo line is: !line!
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ("!word!") do set delete=!line:*%%a=!
    echo delete is: !delete!
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ("!word!!delete!") do set line=!line:%%a=!
    echo line is: !line!
)
endlocal
```