# Can't Set Variable with"FOR" command

Tags: batch-file

i'm trying to set couple of variables from "for /f" command and always get "ECHO is off" when i'm echoing them:

ipst.txt file:

```
1     10.1.1.10
3     10.1.3.10
8     10.1.3.10
```

the batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
set Computerslist=ipst.txt

for /f "tokens=1,2" %%A in (%Computerslist%) do (
    set StationNumber=%%A
    set StationIP=%%B
    echo %StationNumber%
    echo %StationIP%
    )
```

the result is:

```
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
```

that issue prevent me from taking the variales and use them with more loops.
need your help :)

Comment: Are you referencing the "bad" behavior as the output isn't correct? That's propably because of line 1 (`@ECHO OFF`)?

Comment: Your problem is variable expansion. Delayed expansion is needed. Please, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21725323/2861476). Use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and replace `%var%` with `!var!` where needed.

Comment: MC ND - Can you edit my batch here?

Comment: @Ohad_E, please, see answer (and read the link in comment for more information).

Comment: MC ND - Fantastic! i'm still trying to learn more about "set local"! that've been very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MC ND is correct.  Choose one of these 2 ways:

```
@ECHO OFF
set Computerslist=ipst.txt

for /f "tokens=1,2" %%A in (%Computerslist%) do (
    set "StationNumber=%%A" & echo.%%A
    set "StationIP=%%B" & echo.%%B
    )
```

or

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Computerslist=ipst.txt

for /f "tokens=1,2" %%A in (%Computerslist%) do (
    set StationNumber=%%A
    set StationIP=%%B
    echo.!StationNumber!
    echo.!StationIP!
    )
```

Comment: And for completness the third way `call echo(%%StationID%%`

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "Computerslist=ipst.txt"

    for /f "tokens=1,2 usebackq" %%A in ("%Computerslist%") do (
        set "StationNumber=%%A"
        set "StationIP=%%B"
        echo !StationNumber!
        echo !StationIP!
    )
```

But, as indicated in the comments, delayed expansion is only needed if the changed variable is accessed INSIDE the block where the variable is changed. So, this code

```
@ECHO OFF
    set "Computerslist=ipst.txt"

    for /f "tokens=1,2 usebackq" %%A in ("%Computerslist%") do (
        set "StationNumber=%%A"
        set "StationIP=%%B"
    )
    echo %StationNumber%
    echo %StationIP%
```

Here, access to the variable value is not done in the same block where it where changed, so, no delayed expansion required.

EDITED - as stated in comments, this last code does not list all the lines in the file. As the for loops over them, previous values are overwritten and the variables hold only the last asigned value, that will be echoed to console. My fault, bad sample selected.

Comment: Of course in the 2nd example you would only display the results for the last item in Computerslist... which is fine if there is only one item.  OP will have to deecide.

Comment: @RGuggisberg, You are right. My fault to not explain it better. Going to change the answer. Thank you