# Windows 7 Batch File for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

In both cases the directory contains three files named test1.txt, test2.txt, test3.txt

Can someone explain why this works:

```
echo off
set CP=
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    call :concat %%f
)
echo %CP%

:concat
set CP=%CP%;%1
```

output:

```
C:\test>test

C:\test>echo off
;test1.txt;test2.txt;test3.txt

C:\test>
```

But this does not:

```
echo off
set CP=
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    set CP=set CP=%CP%;%%f
)
echo %CP%
```

output:

```
C:\test>test

C:\test>echo off
;test3.txt

C:\test>
```

Comment: Maybe, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21725323/2861476) can help

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with Delayed Expansion.

For example, this will work just like your first example:

```
echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set CP=
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    set CP=!CP!;%%f
)
echo %CP%
ENDLOCAL
```

When Delayed Expansion is enabled then variables surrounded with `!` are evaluated on *each iteration* instead of only the first time when the loop is parsed (which is how variables surrounded with `%` are parsed).

Your first example works because the processing is done in a `CALL` statement which passes control to another segment of the batch file which is technically outside the loop so it is parsed individually each time it is executed.