# Get substring from path in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

So I wanted to automate importing tasks into task scheduler with a batch script. The idea is to iterate throught xml files in given directory and import them one by one. Right now my script looks like this:

```
@echo on

setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

for %%e in ("%~dp0*.xml") do (
schtasks /create /tn "%%~dpne" /ru "System" /xml "%%~e")

pause
```

The problem I have is with /tn flag in this script, because "%%~dpne" returns full path of xml file(without extension) for example:

```
C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Pent\Projects\DF\TASK_DAILY
```

and I only need this part:

```
Pent\Projects\DF\TASK_DAILY
```

How can I extract this substring ? Cheers.

Comment: [Batch File - Get Sub Path By Subtracting One String Variable From Another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830611/batch-file-get-sub-path-by-subtracting-one-string-variable-from-another)

Comment: The task doesn't make sense. There is no point in uning `%~dp0` as a dynamic variable here, if you are specifically wanting a non dynamic substring of that location too. The only possibility would be that you wanted a substring of the last four branches, but using a  `%~dp0` means that there may not ever be four of those in total. I think we need a better explanation of how you want the task name substring to be determined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find your use of `disabledelayedexpansion` odd, since that is the default condition. Perhaps we have a case of overcropping from a routine where delayed expansion is enabled....

Since `~dpne` would be evaluated to the same as `~dp0` without the filename, you could use

```
set "mypath=%~dp0"
set "mypath=%mypath:*microsoft\=%"
for %%e in ("%~dp0*.xml") do (
schtasks /create /tn "%mypath%%%~ne" /ru "System" /xml "%%~e")
```

Using the second `set` to replace all characters up to the first occurrence of `microsoft\` (case-insensitive) with *nothing*, and using the resultant value of `mypath`.

**Note : untested**